# Не получатеся добавить товар ссылкой через скрипт

Tags: javascript, tilda

Добавляю товар скриптом через

```
#order:{Name}={price}:::image={URL}
```

[Полный код скрипта](https://pastebin.com/nTPQrdCS)

Товар в корзину добавляется, но при попытке сделать заказ, выводит надпись, что товара нет в наличии. В каталоге товар с таким названием имеется, количество его неограничено. При добавлении же товара штатным способом, все ок. Можно ли как-то отключить проверку наличия товара или же по-другому добавить его через скрипт?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.